# Maximize value of recurrent function in coin flip game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Going through for [Maximizing expected value of coin reveal game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927140/maximizing-expected-value-of-coin-reveal-game/1928582#1928582?newreg=fa2d388a66cc4109ad716a0a79afd446)

the answer says that the optimal value of the utility function (average cost per flip is 25).
I see that the function in the numerator has a recursive form, is the author using a more general form to get the optimal value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function does not have a recursive form. It is given explicitly for even $m$ as

$$
F(m)=\frac m2\left(1+2^{-m}\binom m{\frac m2}\right)\;.
$$

What you mistook for a recursive form is an explicit form for odd $m$, which is given in terms of the form for even $m$:

\begin{eqnarray}
F(m)
&=&
\frac m{m-1}F(m-1)
\\
&=&
\frac m{m-1}\cdot\frac{m-1}2\left(1+2^{-(m-1)}\binom{m-1}{\frac{m-1}2}\right)
\\
&=&
\frac m2\left(1+2^{-(m-1)}\binom{m-1}{\frac{m-1}2}\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Incidentally, the answer is wrong about the maximum of the expected payoff per coin

$$
v(m)=\frac{F(m)-1}m\;,
$$

which is in fact at $m=23$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did you derive this (m=23) numerically or can you do it analytically/or quick way to get an estimate (which is what I'm struggling with). Thanks

Comment: @highvelocityevent: I added a comment under Chas Brown's answer in the original question and linked to a Wolfram|Alpha table with the numbers. I don't immediately see how to do it analytically; you'd need quite a good estimate of the central binomial coefficients for that – I don't think just using the main term $\binom{2n}n\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ would yield a maximum.