# Coin tossing game without best strategy?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Suppose I have tossed $n=8$ fair coins in private. For each heads/tails you guess correctly, you get $1. You can ask me one yes/no question about the coins before your guesses. Lets assume each previous coin is revealed to you before you guess the next(but your guess is at the beginning). What strategy has maximum expected value?

I think the best strategy is to ask what the first coin is, then your expected is $\frac{n+1}{2}$. But im not sure how to prove this, or how to turn "yes/no question" into a mathematical statement.

What can we say about general $n$ or if the coin is biased? What happens if the previous coins are never revealed?

This post [Maximizing expected value of coin reveal game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927140/maximizing-expected-value-of-coin-reveal-game) is similar but doesnt prove the strategy is best

Comment: I wonder if "is the number of heads an element of $~\{3,4,5\}$" might be a more profitable question to ask.

Comment: It may also be affected by whether your guess each time can take account of coins already seen as in the linked question

Comment: @Henry Yes, without that Id think we're just guessing the number of heads, it sounds much easier but I could be wrong

Comment: "Are there more heads than tails ?" guarantees $4$ hits , but I am pretty sure that there is an even more clever question.

Comment: A good strategy would be  to ask "are there more heads than tails"? If the answer is yes, guess only heads, else guess only tails.  The expected value follows

 $$E[2n] = n\;(1 + \binom{2*n}{n}/4^n)$$
 $$E[2n+1] = (n+\frac{1}{2})\;(1 + \binom{2*n}{n}/4^n)$$

For $E[8]$ you get $5+ \frac{3}{23}$

Comment: For biased coins you should ask: "is the ratio of obtained heads to tails"  greater than the bias, and apply a similar strategy.

Comment: @user3257842 You can do better with this question: notice that if answer was 'no' and you've already seen four heads, then the rest are tails.

Comment: If the answer was no, then you're already set towards guessing tails, before you've even seen any coins. Seeing coins won't change the strategy.

Comment: Oops. My bad, poor example. If you've seen four _tails_ then heads are more probable ($\frac{70}{163}$ that all remaining results are heads and $\frac{56}{163}$ there's only one tail).

Comment: Anyway , $4$ hits can be guaranteed whether the coins are biased or not.

Comment: @user3257842 My strategy beats yours for n=10

Answer (score 0):

> how to turn "yes/no question" into a mathematical statement

"One yes/no question" means a set of sequences $S$ for which the answer is "yes". For every set (of which there are $2^{256}$), at every guess you can compute $P(H_i | V_1, V_2, ..., V_{i-1}, S)$ and guess "heads" if and only if it's more than $\frac{1}{2}$ which gives the best strategy for this question. When different questions correspond to the same set $S$, their strategies are equivalent. Thus, the total space of strategies is large but finite and the maximum exists.

Finding it may be tricky (I don't know the solution) but notion of [enthropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) probably helps. You can only get 1 bit of information out of a yes/no question and it seems that the best question have to be close to that - divide a set of results in half or almost in half. You would obtain 8 bit from learning the whole sequence - so you want to get close $\frac{7}{8}$ bits on average from any toss - so $S$ should include 90 sequences where first coin is "tails" and depending on the result of the first coin 70% results where the second one is "tails" and so on. That would give roughly $0.7$ win probability per coin, 5.6 wins on average.

So, you could write a table with 128 rows. First, you fill 90(~70%) cells of the first column with 1s and the remaining 38 with 0s. Then for each block of the previous column, you fill the next column the same way - 56 1s and 34 0s for the first 1, 27 1s and 11 0s for the first 0 and so on. Then you may ask: "converting heads to 1 and tails to 0, is the sequence you obtained in this table?". If the answer is "yes", you always guess "heads", otherwise "tails".